# Protocols for device cannot be changed

Tags: remote, lirc

I am trying to run "ir-keytable -p nec" to change protocols but I get "protocols for device can not be changed". Is there any way I can change this or I have to reinstall?

Comment: is `ir-keytable -p nec` the full command? did you try with `sudo`? what's the output of `sudo ir-keytable`